# GoogleMobileAds with Unity Ads - Reward based video ad event handler issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, rewardedvideoad

I have a game project which uses GoogleMobileAds with Unity Ads to serve banner, interstitial and rewarded video ads (with unity ads as mediation network). And everything is set properly (admob config., sdk and adapter files etc.) and seems to be working. All three types of ads are loading and showing without an error. 
But there is a slight issue. I'm having hard to time respond reward based video ads **OnAdRewarded** event. I've tried a couple of options including running reward command in event handler (not working) and using a flag and checking its value (not working either). As far as I know googlemobileads events are not raising in the main thread. So flag should do the trick but it doesn't. Is there anyone who has encountered this problem and found a solution?

My code is as follows:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class RewardBasedAdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd;

    public int rewardAmount = 25;
    public bool isPlayerRewarded = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
        rewardBasedVideoAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        // RewardBasedVideoAd is a singleton, so handlers should only be registered once.
        ..
        rewardBasedVideoAd.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        ..
        RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    }

    public void RequestRewardBasedVideo(){...}

    ...

    private void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        //Debug.Log("HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded event received.");
        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;
        //Debug.Log("User rewarded with: " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);

        // Option 1
        // Directly execute reward command (not working)
        // It's a singleton. Could this be the problem?
        CoinTracker.Instance.CoinCount += rewardAmount;

        // Option 2
        // Use flag and check it's value in Update method (not working either)
        isPlayerRewarded = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isPlayerRewarded)
        {
            CoinTracker.Instance.CoinCount += rewardAmount;
            isPlayerRewarded = false;
        }
    }
}
```